# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'object.keys(routeConfigs)')

Tags: react-native, expo, routeconfig

## This is the error I am receiving. Please tell me what file you need to see. Apologies if the problem is not to the point, I am a noob here.

*First image shows the error*
[image: error as on simulator]
*Below is the file which calls for stack navigator.*

## This file calls for stacknavigator

*If you need anything else, please tell me, I'll add it in further edits*

```js
import React from "react";
import { Easing, Animated, Dimensions } from "react-native";

//import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation'; 
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator,DrawerItems} from 'react-navigation-drawer';
//import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-bottom-tabs';

import { Block } from "galio-framework";

// screens
import HomeActivity from '../components/HomeActivity.js';
import ProfileActivity from '../components/ProfileActivity.js';
import Results from '../components/Results.js';
// import HomeActivity from "../screens/Home";
// import Onboarding from "../screens/Onboarding";
import Pro from "../components/Pro";
import Profile from "../components/Profile";
// import Register from "../screens/Register";
// import Elements from "../screens/Elements";
// import Articles from "../screens/Articles";
// drawer
import CustomDrawerContent from "./Menu";

// header for screens
import Icon from "../components/Icon";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import { argonTheme, tabs } from "../constants";

const { width } = Dimensions.get("screen");

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
//const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function ElementsStack(props) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator mode="card" headerMode="screen">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Elements"
        component={Profile}
        options={{
          header: ({ navigation, scene }) => (
            <Header title="Elements" navigation={navigation} scene={scene} />
          ),
          cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "#F8F9FE" }
        }}
      />
            <Stack.Screen
        name="Pro"
        component={Pro}
        options={{
          header: ({ navigation, scene }) => (
            <Header
              title=""
              back
              white
              transparent
              navigation={navigation}
              scene={scene}
            />
          ),
          headerTransparent: true
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function ArticlesStack(props) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator mode="card" headerMode="screen">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Articles"
        component={Articles}
        options={{
          header: ({ navigation, scene }) => (
            <Header title="Articles" navigation={navigation} scene={scene} />
          ),
          cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "#F8F9FE" }
        }}
      />
            <Stack.Screen
        name="Pro"
        component={Pro}
        options={{
          header: ({ navigation, scene }) => (
            <Header
              title=""
              back
              white
              transparent
              navigation={navigation}
              scene={scene}
            />
          ),
          headerTransparent: true
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function ProfileStack(props) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Profile" mode="card" headerMode="screen">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileActivity}
        options={{
          header: ({ navigation, scene }) => (
            <Header
              transparent
              white
              title="Profile"
              navigation={navigation}
              scene={scene}
            />
          ),
          cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF" },
          headerTransparent: true
        }}
      />
            <Stack.Screen
        name="Pro"
        component={Pro}
        options={{
          header: ({ navigation, scene }) => (
            <Header
              title=""
              back
              white
              transparent
              navigation={navigation}
              scene={scene}
            />
          ),
          headerTransparent: true
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function HomeStack(props) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator mode="card" headerMode="screen">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeActivity}
        options={{
          header: ({ navigation, scene }) => (
            <Header
              title="Home"
              search
              options
              navigation={navigation}
              scene={scene}
            />
          ),
          cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "#F8F9FE" }
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Pro"
        component={Pro}
        options={{
          header: ({ navigation, scene }) => (
            <Header
              title=""
              back
              white
              transparent
              navigation={navigation}
              scene={scene}
            />
          ),
          headerTransparent: true
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function OnboardingStack(props) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator mode="card" headerMode="none">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Jobs"
        component={Results}
        option={{
          headerTransparent: true
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="App" component={AppStack} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function AppStack(props) {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}
      drawerStyle={{
        backgroundColor: "white",
        width: width * 0.8
      }}
      drawerContentOptions={{
        activeTintcolor: "white",
        inactiveTintColor: "#000",
        activeBackgroundColor: "transparent",
        itemStyle: {
          width: width * 0.75,
          backgroundColor: "transparent",
          paddingVertical: 16,
          paddingHorizonal: 12,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          overflow: "hidden"
        },
        labelStyle: {
          fontSize: 18,
          marginLeft: 12,
          fontWeight: "normal"
        }
      }}
      initialRouteName="Home"
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStack} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileStack} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Results" component={OnboardingStack} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Elements" component={ElementsStack} />
      {/* <Drawer.Screen name="Articles" component={ArticlesStack} /> */}
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So based on the error i would say that `validateRouteConfigMap.js` is getting an object(routeConfigs) that you've not yet defined or passed in as `undefined` or you have not set a default value for. Remember `Object.keys(ARRAY_OR_OBJECT_VARIABLE)` requires a variable of object type (besides null)

Comment: But I have not used any variable which calls for routeConfigs, maybe it is due to stack navigator. Can you show me how to fix it?

Comment: You'd have to show a snippet of the offending code. There isn't enough information in your screenshot to give your a more accurate answer from my point of view

Comment: Done, uploaded the snippet which might help. Kindly go through it